# How to mount a qnx partition as read -write enabled only for executing particular lines of code?

Tags: linux, mount, qnx, qnx-neutrino

ie the partition of interest is already mounted as read-only.the partition need to be mounted as a rw enabled partition for executing particular lines of script alone.After that the partition should go to it's previous state of read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remout a partition read-write:

```
mount /mnt/mountpoint -oremount,rw
```

and to remout read-only

```
mount /mnt/mountpoint -oremount,ro
```

Comment: Is this qnx6 or another version?  If so, please specify that.  (This does not work for me on qnx7, although one of the other answers does.)

Answer (score 5):

Question is for QNX operating system. And correct way to remount partition as read/write can be done using below command.

```
mount -uw /
```

Answer (score 1):

you may be interested in **remount** option.

for example, this command is widely used in rooted androids.

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

> mount(8) - Linux man page
>
> > Filesystem Independent Mount Options
> >
> > > remount
> > >
> > > > Attempt to remount an already-mounted filesystem. This is commonly used to change the mount flags for a filesystem, especially to make a readonly filesystem writeable. It does not change device or mount point.
> > > >
> > > > The remount functionality follows the standard way how the mount command works with options from fstab. It means the mount command doesn't read fstab (or mtab) only when a device and dir are fully specified.
> > > >
> > > > mount -o remount,rw /dev/foo /dir
> > > >
> > > > After this call all old mount options are replaced and arbitrary stuff from fstab is ignored, except the loop= option which is internally generated and maintained by the mount command.
> > > >
> > > > mount -o remount,rw /dir
> > > >
> > > > After this call mount reads fstab (or mtab) and merges these options with options from command line ( -o ).